# Change information in modal when clicking on different image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, frontend

I have a front-end only project, where I have a couple of images, and when clicking on one image the modal pops up with details about the image.

Since I have around 50 images, it would be too much to create a new page with a modal on each image, therefore I would like to know if there is any JavaScript function that can handle the different information on modal based on what image is clicked.

F.x: Car image is clicked and modal pops up about detail of the car, modal is closed and when another image of a bicycle is clicked - modal pops up with details of the bicycle.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: The answer is yes. You can have one div and change the content using innerHTML of the tags in the modal div

Comment: Thank you for feedback @mplungjan, I will sure take a look at it and hopefully next time I'll ask better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this

```js
const images = [{
    "url": "https://picsum.photos/id/1020/367/267",
    "title": "Bear on a mountain",
    "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
  },
  {
    "url": "https://picsum.photos/id/1024/367/267",
    "title": "Eagle in flight",
    "description" : "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
  },
  {
    "url": "https://picsum.photos/id/1025/367/267",
    "title": "Doggie in a blanket",
    "description" : "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."    
  }
];
const html = images.map((img, i) => `<img src="${img.url}" title="${img.title}" data-idx="${i}"/>`);
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const modal = document.getElementById("modal");
container.innerHTML = html.join(" ");
container.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName == "IMG") {
    const idx = tgt.dataset.idx; console.log(idx, images[idx].title)
    modal.querySelector(".title").innerHTML = images[idx].title;
    modal.querySelector(".desc").innerHTML = images[idx].description;
    modal.classList.remove("hide");
  }
})
modal.querySelector(".close").addEventListener("click",function() { modal.classList.add("hide") })
```

```css
#modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 3px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

#container img { cursor: pointer; }

.close { float:right; }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="modal" class="hide"><div class="close">X</div><h1 class="title"></h1><div class="desc"></div></div>
```

Comment: I added an `X` to the modal

Comment: So I can see the image and title is coming from javascript, but let's say I need to design it properly - should I all data store in Javascript (subtitle, description, etc) ? And than point it in html and style it in CSS just like in regular html template?

Comment: I have added two spans in the modal. The first span could be a header and more text could be in the javascript. You could give the images an ID and keep the text in another object entry: `const images = [{
    "url": "https://picsum.photos/id/1020/367/267",
    "title": "Bear on a mountain", "description": "The <i>bear</i> is turning away from us and trundling up the hill"<
  },`

Comment: I created <span> for description, added description after title   `"url": "https://picsum.photos/id/1020/367/267",
    "title": "Bear on a mountain",
    "description": "The <i>bear</i> is turning away from us and trundling up the hill"` and pointed at it : `<img src="${img.url}" title="${img.title}" description="${img.description}"/>` and `modal.innerHTML = tgt.getAttribute("title", "description");` , but it is still not showing anything

Comment: That is not valid JavaScript. You cannot get two attributes in one call

Comment: Please see update - I use the index now instead